# IN , AND query in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I want to make a query on spring boot using hibernate. But I have tried in condition and criteria, but it seems not to work.

I want to make a SQL query: `SELECT * FROM db1_test.device where user_id in " + customerIds + ") and 'app_id' like '%text-v2%`

If I enter this into MYSQL it should be work. `user_id` is a String that the user type in.

I got this error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Comment: You miss an opening parenthesis in your sql request

Comment: it still showing error after I correct it